# navbar and control alignment angular+BS3

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Am new to angular and bootstrap. Am reading and playing with some sample projects that I have found online

I am trying to create index page with navbar that goes across width of page and then a search box, similar to google

My code is

```
<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-primary ng-scope" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HELLO WORLD</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="search ng-scope">
        <input class="typeahead search-field" type="text" placeholder="Search" autofocus="">
    </div>


</div>
```

What I get is the navbar and the search box just below the navbar without any gap.

How do I maintain a navbar and have the search control about half way to the page?

My css
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOqQX.png)

Comment: are you looking for something like this - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yJWXBv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to do something with the CSS to put padding or a margin at the top if you want it centered in the window.

You could wrap all your content in a div and give it a class with styles similar to this:

https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/